# Go Redefined type formating and methods

Tags: go

Here is a basic go program

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "time"
)

type myTime time.Time

func main() {
        my := myTime(time.Now())
        fmt.Println(my)

        normal := time.Now()
        fmt.Println(normal)
}
```

And the corresponding output

```
{63547112172 291468455 0x545980}
2014-09-23 23:36:12.292132305 +0000 UTC
```

I would like to know why myTime prints diffrently than time.Time. They basically are supposed to be from the same type... Also, if I try to access any method of time.Time, let's say, Day, it's available for "normal" but not for "my".

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your new type does not inherit methods from `time.Time`. [To quote the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Properties_of_types_and_values):

> The declared type does not inherit any methods bound to the existing type

Since there is no `String` method, it won't print a meaningful value. You need to implement that yourself.

Your other option is to embed `time.Time` in your own type. That way you can include the functionality of `time.Time` but also add your own functionality.

Playground link: http://play.golang.org/p/PY6LIBoP6H

```
type myTime struct {
    time.Time
}

func (t myTime) String() string {
    return "<Custom format here>"
}

func main() {
    my := myTime{time.Now()}
    fmt.Println(my)

    normal := time.Now()
    fmt.Println(normal)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`fmt.Println` uses the `String()` method (or rather the [`fmt.Stringer` interface](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Stringer)) when formatting a type as a string, if it is available. When you create a new type using an underlying type (in your case `time.Time`):

```
type myTime time.Time
```

You will not inherit the methodset of the underlying type. Therefore, `myTime` has no `String()` method, so fmt will use the default format for a struct.